# Combination of two columns from text file and finding count with reference to third column in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, hash-of-hashes

I am trying to read the in.txt file and generate an output file out.txt Using Perl. I tried with Hashes but not getting exact output.

Is there a way to do this in Perl.

Combination of two columns and providing comments on the basis of third column.

**in.txt**

```
Template,Account,Active
123456,123,N
123456,456,Y
321478,456,Y
123456,123,N
321478,456,Y
```

**out.txt**

```
Account,Template,Active,NotActive
123,123456,0,2
456,321478,2,0
456,123456,1,0
```

Comment: Could you please show the code you tried?

Comment: do you accept other solutions than perl?

Comment: You can easily solve this with sqlite if you know a little bit of SQL. That might be easier for you than writing a program. Look for how to _import_ a CSV file, and then how to group columns together and _sum up_ only if a column is a certain value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my $filename = 'input.txt';
my %yhash;
my %nhash;
if (open(my $ifh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)) {
    while (my $row = <$ifh>) {
    next if ($row =~ /^#/m);
    chomp $row;
    my @values = split(',',$row);
    my $value = join '',@values ;
    my $lastchar = substr $value , -1;
    my $firstval = substr $value ,0,9;
    if ($lastchar eq "N"){
              if (exists($nhash{firstval})){ $nhash{firstval}++; }
              $nhash{$firstval}++;
    }elsif($lastchar eq "Y"){
              if (exists($yhash{firstval})){ $yhash{firstval}++; }
              $yhash{$firstval}++;
    }else{
             print "nothin\n";

    }
    }
    close $ifh;
    } else {
    warn "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    }


   open(FH, '>', 'out.txt') or die $!;
   print FH "Account,Template,Active,NotActive\n";
   while (my ($key, $value) = each(%nhash)) {
    my $account = substr $key ,6,3;
    my $template = substr $key ,0,6;
    my $active = "0";
    my $notactive = "$value";
    print FH "$account,$template,$active,$notactive \n";
   }
  while (my ($key, $value) = each(%yhash)) {
    my $account = substr $key ,6,3;
    my $template = substr $key ,0,6;
    my $active = "$value";
    my $notactive = "0";
    print FH "$account,$template,$active,$notactive \n";
  }
  close (FH);
```

Comment: pleasw check the answer...i have written and its working as expected

Comment: hi Rajneesh...please provide feedback on the answer provided

Answer (score 3):

This works as well:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
open my $fh, "<", "in.txt" or die $!;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    next if($line =~ /Account/);
    my @line = split ',', $line;
    $data{$line[1]}{$line[0]}{'Y'} = 0 if(!defined $data{$line[1]}{$line[0]}{'Y'});
    $data{$line[1]}{$line[0]}{'N'} = 0 if(!defined $data{$line[1]}{$line[0]}{'N'});
    $data{$line[1]}{$line[0]}{$line[2]} ++;
}
close $fh;
open my $FH, ">", "out.txt" or die $!;
    print $FH "Account,Template,Active,NotActive\n";
    foreach my $key (sort keys %data) {
        foreach my $key2 (sort keys %{$data{$key}}) {
            print $FH "$key,$key2,$data{$key}{$key2}{'Y'},$data{$key}{$key2}{'N'}\n";
        }
    }
close $FH;
```

You can also replace these two lines

```
$data{$line[1]}{$line[0]}{'Y'} = 0 if(!defined $data{$line[1]}{$line[0]}{'Y'});
$data{$line[1]}{$line[0]}{'N'} = 0 if(!defined $data{$line[1]}{$line[0]}{'N'});
```

with

```
$data{$line[1]}{$line[0]}{$_} //= 0 foreach ('Y', 'N');
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a `perl` solution, but this works fine with `awk`:

**AWK 1-liner**:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";print "Account,Template,Active,NotActive"}NR>1{if($3=="Y"){a[$2 FS $1]++}else{b[$2 FS $1]++}}END{for(i in a){print i OFS a[i] OFS b[i]+0}for(u in b){if(b[u] && !a[u]){print u OFS a[u]+0 OFS b[u]}}}' input_file | sort -n
```

**AWK script**:

```
# BEGIN rule(s)

BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = "," #defines input/output field separator as ,
        print "Account,Template,Active,NotActive" #print the header
}

# Rule(s)

NR > 1 { # from the 2nd line of the file
        if ($3 == "Y") { # if the 3rd field is at Y
                a[$2 FS $1]++ #increment the array  indexed by $2 FS $1 
        } else {
                b[$2 FS $1]++ #do the same when N with the other array
        }
}

# END rule(s)

END {
        for (i in a) { # loop on all values of the arrays and print the content
                print i OFS a[i] OFS (b[i] + 0)
        }
        for (u in b) {
                if (b[u] && ! a[u]) { # do the same with the nonactive array and avoid double printing
                        print u OFS (a[u] + 0) OFS b[u]
                }
        }
} #pipe the output to a numerical sort to perform the proper ordering of the output
```

**DEMO:**

Input:

```
$ cat input_file 
Template,Account,Active
123456,123,N
123456,456,Y
321478,456,Y
123456,123,N
321478,456,Y
123457,125,N
123457,125,Y
```

**output:**

```
Account,Template,Active,NotActive
123,123456,0,2
125,123457,1,1
456,123456,1,0
456,321478,2,0
```